# Is it possible to make "redirect_url" NOT open in the browser window with Google OAuth2?

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am writing an application that requires authentication using the [OAuth2 Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oauth-2.0/info). I have managed to use the [Web Server App authentication mechanism](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) and it's working quite well, the only problem is that I am handling the `redirect_url` within the program itself and I don't want the browser to make the request in a new tab.

If it were possible, the ideal solution would be that google server would send the request to me directly, or that it would open and close the browser tab/window.

Perhaps this approach is not the most appropriate, if so please let me know how to do this better.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Typically the redirect doesn't open a new tab (it makes a new request though).

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi The problem is, that with this kind of authentication I need to open a consent window in the browser, then the consent window redirects to the given url and of course, it does perform the request. My program does handle the request and it's ok, but the browser tab is opened and there is nothing to do about it, because it's impossible to close a browser tab with javascript, that was not opened by javascript. My temporary solution, is to return some HTML telling the user that the program received the code, but it would be cleaner if I could show that message directly.

Comment: And how do you open the browser window in the first place? For example, if it's a desktop application that opens the browser just to get user's consent, it can emulate users actions (including closing the window) by sending messages to the browser window. If it's a web application, it could open the consent with javascript (`window.open()`) so that it would be able to close the opened window with `window.close()`, etc.

Comment: The reall application has no user interface, it will however interact with the user through the file manager. I was thinking of something like that. I open the browser window through `xdg-open $url`, it's a linux program so it is intentionally non-portable, or at least for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible I am actually doing just that in my .Net application using a web browser control.  You have tagged this Google Oauth so I am assuming you are doing this with Googles auth servers.   I suspect you are using one of Googles client libraries which are built to open it in a new browser window by default.   The Google .Net client library for example is designed to do this.

The trick may require that instead of using a web credentials you use native or other type credentials which do not require a redirect URI.  These credentials are normally used for installed applications but they can be used for web.  It may be possible to do it with web credentials but I think its going to depend a little on what you are doing exactly.

**Google Oauth2 flow:**

The first step in the flow is creating the URL for the user to authenticate.  This is a webpage there is nothing you can do to change that.   So your application will need to be able to display a webpage to the user.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code
```

by supplying urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob you are basically telling the auth server to just return the code to where you sent it from.

The code is returned to you and you will need to swap it. This call is a HTTP POST.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

response

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4"
}
```

Now you have a refresh toke and an access token.   you can refresh your access token using another HTTP POst call.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Response

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_XK16As2ZHlScqOxGtntIlevNcasMSPwGiE3pe5ANZfrmJTcsI3ZtAjv4sDrPDRnQ",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600
}
```

So as long as you can embed the auth URL into your application you can fetch it yourself.  You don't need the redirect URI.  my tutorial on [google 3 legged oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

Comment: I don't understand if the browser is involved or if it isn't! If it isn't, then I would need to provide some method to show the page to the user without using the browser, I was already thinking of that, but in my case it's difficult. Because I don't have access to a web browser control, so I would need to write a mini web browser my self, which might be simple or really difficult, because I suppose that it would need to execute some js.

Comment: Also, I know about the code and exchanging it with an `access_token`, my application does authenticate correctly.

Comment: There is no way around that the initial consent must be preformed VIA that web page.  But yes you could create your own mini browser.

Answer (score 3):

**Fair warning**, haven't used oAuth like this but I do have an idea:

Can't you just open the oauth request in a pop-up with `window.open()`?
Getting the parent of the popup is then as easy using `window.opener`.

After OAuth validation you could refresh the parent with:
`window.opener.location.reload();`

You could then simply use `window.close()` to close the popup.

This way no new tabs will be opened and your application will remain the active tab.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're already using non-portable xdg-open, you probably can use another external tool (`xdotool`) and emulate users keystrokes with it:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "Chrome" windowfocus key 'ctrl+w'
```

This will send `ctrl+w` (close tab) to visible chrome instance

Keep in mind there may be more than one browser window open.

Comment: What is `xdotool`? Is it standard like `xdg-open`?

Comment: [Xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool). It's not as widespread as xdg-open, but available as a package for most major Linux distributions.